# Office/Sharepoint developer tools will not show up in Visual Studio(despite being installed)

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, vsto

In Visual Studio, when I right click -> add -> new item, I should receive an option with "Office/SharePoint", like the image in this link
[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tNEB.png)

But in my case, it does not show up, as seen in the picture in this link
[What actually appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unsYs.png)

I have already installed Office/SharePoint development workload, which contains Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio, as seen in this link
[Tools seem to be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdMMY.png)

Comment: Do you see project templates when you create a new add-in project?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I have templates for starter projects like 'SharePoint Add-in' or 'SharePoint 2019'. Only when I try to add new items, they do not show up